# How to generate packed_trx for push transaction?

Tags: cleos

Where can I find documents about this?

Or does it have some descriptions instead of c++/js code?
[image]

Comment: First thing: please insert the code into your question instead of an image. Also some details about what you are trying to achieve, what the name of your contract is and the action you want call. Maybe the official [docu for RPC](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#push_transaction) calls will help. Also there is [git hub issue](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5341). Maybe this will help as well.

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot, just know that the latest cleos have this feature